# How do I ensure the file I send to an external printer will print correctly?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, pdf, color-profile, digital-printing

Hope you can help here?
I have an Ilustrator 2020 design which I want to get printed on A3 (Giclee).
I have an ICC profile (seems to be RGB) from my external printer who will print for me.
When I softproof using this profile, colours look fine.
When I use the save as PDF feature, colours look fine. (I select convert colours to destination and select the ICC profile from the printer).
When I use the print option and then select the ICC profile as above, the colours come out highly saturated.
I am not sure which option is the safe approach when sending to printer. Will the save as approach come out saturated too? Whilst this file looks OK on my screen, when I sent to my inbox and check colour on my phone, again it looks saturated.
A little confused here. Any help will be really appreciated.
Thanks,
Ed.

Comment: Is your system properly calibrated? If not, you've no way to know which is correct.

Comment: Hi - system is properly calibrated using a Spyder X Pro. :)

Comment: What is your conversion intent?

Answer (score 4):

The ICC profile you received from the print provider is for *their equipment*. You should *not* expect the ICC profile to render proper colors on *your* equipment.

For accurate color from *your* printer, you need to calibrate the printer and create an ICC profile for *your* printer.

If you want to ensure proper color from a print provider, **ask them for a color proof**. They will create a sample of how the piece will look using their equipment.

(And **always** use either Adobe Acrobat or Adobe Reader to view PDFs if you are concerned with color. All other viewers are unsatisfactory.)

Comment: Thanks. So in this particular case when I am getting 2 different visual results when outputting to a PDF, I am not sure which version to run with. Would soft-proofing in Illustrator using their ICC profile not get "in the ball-park" results? The outputted PDF generated using the "Print" option in miles out from the soft-proofing on screen whilst the "save as" generated PDF is a match (but still looks saturated when viewed on a phone).